Supply external signal to MOSFET PWM
I fear I'm missing something very basic here but I want to remove the default signal from the 555 chip on the board and instead input my own. As you can see below I've cut the signal on the board and soldered my own wires. I assumed if I took the positive input previously going to a potentiometer and connected it to the gate of the MOSFETs it should switch them on but instead the seem to be on by default and even more bafflingly when I apply the gate voltage the output voltage from the PWM drops by two volts.
I don't know if I've broken the module or I'm profoundly misunderstanding something. Any explanation would be very much appreciated!



Welcome! Please draw a schematic. Does the board and your external signal source share ground?

Circuit diagram with values immensely useful. || Text somewhat unclear - eg "when I apply the gate voltage the output voltage from the PWM drops by two volts." Are "the gate voltage" and "the PWM" the same voltage. Measured where. What is the load (gate resistor to ground?) . What is the PWM source and frequency and load capbility. What was the 555 signal level. What is your new signal level? What is the MOSFET type? What is its Vgs_th?|| A well labelled diagram will answer much of these and more. || To give good answers people need to know what you can see measure and tell.

Thanks both. I'm afraid my lack of knowledge limits my ability to answer many of your questions. My assumption was that the input to the potentiometer (where the black wire is connected) was supplying the 555 and so if I connected this to the point in the circuit where the 555 output was going to the MOSFET gates (where the red wire is connected) it it would switch them on. However they seem to be on when nothing is corrected to the red wire and as far as I can tell with my basic multimeter the gate voltage is zero. I'll understand if it's not possible to help with only this information.

The RU6888 is an N Channel MOSFET with turn on voltage of 3V typical and 4V max. || It should be turned off with no signal and gate grounded by a resistor. You appear to have a 10k (103 label) resistor from signal in to gate and a 15K (153) from gate to ground. If the non 103 end of the 153 is grounded (as I expect) then the FET should be of with no input signal. ||

With NO signal on your input wire measure voltage at FET gate (left hand pin). Should be zero relative to ground. || RH FET pin is probably ground.|| How do you know the connector pin soldered to is ground? | It should probably have 0 ohms to FET rh pin. || apply uour input signal to red wire as shown AND FET rh pin. Results? ||
